# fetch last item of core data array

Tags: swift, fetch, uiimage, binary-data

In my swift code below my goal is fetch the last image of the core data array.  Right now my code is having a runtime error with indexpath. I dont know if you need to use a index path to do this. I have also added a screenshot that features all of the core data info.

[image: pic of core data]

```
var pic = UIImageView()
func loadImage(){
    if let imageData = itemNamez[IndexPath.last(pic)] {
        
        let coredataLoadedimage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        pic.image = coredataLoadedimage
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can access array last index like I have done in code.

  ```
  let arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
  print(arr.last ?? "")
  ```

Comment: This does not work for a binary image. Can you show me how to do this with a binary image?